# DatabaseError with django-avatar

Tags: python, database, django, avatar

I just downloaded django-avatar and I am getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'my_app.avatar_avatar' doesn't exist")
```

**Traceback**

```
.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/avatar/views.py in change
93.    avatar, avatars = _get_avatars(request.user)
▶ Local vars
.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/avatar/views.py in _get_avatars
45.    if primary_avatar:
▶ Local vars
```

To clarify, I'm not using the `django.contrib.auth app` for my users. 
How do I set up my user model with django-avatar?

Comment: maybe you have to sync your db?

Comment: Yap, thanks that was it!

Comment: I didn't find that on the docs. that's why. Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the commments, syncing the db does the trick here.